# Travelling one way via boat, USA → Turkey

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, turkey, cruising, working-visas

Family is planning on travelling to Turkey for long term (they will work there).  They have a dog. They've found a cruise that allows dogs and stops at various ports in Europe.

Would they be allowed to disembark permanently at their destination, if the cruise stops there? They both have visas.

Are there boats made especially for such trips? Not cruises, but just a way to travel (with dog) from one country to another? They're hoping to avoid plane, but will probably end up doing that if no good boat solution exists.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff mixed up here. Let's start with their visas. There's more to working in a foreign country than hopping off a boat and getting a job. Do they have appropriate visas that allow long term stay, and work? If so, then yes, they can disembark. They have a cruise, you say, or maybe they don't because you're asking about passenger ships, or maybe planes. With a dog. Or perhaps not. Please edit this into something coherent, and confirm they have the right visas

Comment: @ReddHerring "they both have visas."  There's also nothing in the question to suggest that they're considering traveling without their dog.